# How to pick row from DataGridView?

Tags: c#

how i can move on rows in DataGridView and when i press [Enter]

i'll get the value of the data in colum - 0 and the row that i stand on hem ?

(when i press [Enter] the cursor move to row+1 and i dont whant this - only this

that i stand on him)

thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGridView has a CurrentRow property.

Handle the KeyDown event for the DataGridView to capture the ENTER key. Set e.Handled to true to stop the ENTER key's default behaviour.

To get the data in column 0 check the CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.

Sample:

```
    private void MyGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            DataGridViewRow currentRow = MyGrid.CurrentRow;
            MessageBox.Show( Convert.ToString(currentRow.Cells[0].Value));
        }
    }
```